# Swift: Draw text using UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, core-graphics, nsattributedstring, uibezierpath

Since I could not find any proper answer on google, here is the problem:
I need to `draw` the shape of an `attributed string`, preferable using `UIBezierPath`. Is there any way one can achieve that?

Comment: "Draw the shape of an attributed string" is exactly what any text element does automatically (UILabel, NSAttributeString.draw(at:), CTLineDraw, etc.). So I'm expecting you mean something more specific than that. What do you plan to do with the UIBezierPath? Getting from NSAttributeString to UIBezierPath is definitely possible via Core Text, but it's a bit of work, and gets quite complicated if you want to handle everything NSAttributedString can do, so it'd be good to understand if you really need all that, or if a simpler solution will address your need. Usually CATextLayer is best.

Comment: my goal is to work with text as with a picture. I want to be able to trim it, cut a circle in the middle, bend etc.

Comment: If you want to treat it as a picture, you don't want a UIBezierPath. That would make your work harder. You want to render it as an image and work on the image. Trimming and cutting are best done with masks, which you can do most easily with CGContext or CATextLayer. If I had to guess what you're doing, I'd guess you really want a CATextLayer, since that gives you access to lots of masking and clipping and CIFilter operations.

Answer (score 3):

your best best is to use somethign like this. Using a bezier path can be quite complicated especially if you are going to be drawing more than one word. It will take a lot of custom work and headaches trying to get the lines drawn in the right order and on the same y position. 
Below will draw out any word you set.

```
var charLayers = [CAShapeLayer]()

  func drawText() {
        for layer in self.charLayers {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        let font = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: fontNameHEre, size: FontSizeHere)! ]
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "myStringHere", attributes: font)
        let charPaths = self.characterPaths(attributedString: attributedString, position: CGPoint(x: 255, y: 632))

        self.charLayers = charPaths.map { path -> CAShapeLayer in
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
            shapeLayer.path = path
            return shapeLayer
        }
}
```

The result is going to be the string you defined. It will be drawn out for you.

Simply call the function `drawText()` wherever you need the drawing to take place

-------- EDIT

sorry forgot to add in the important function

see below

```
    func characterPaths(attributedString: NSAttributedString, position: CGPoint) -> [CGPath] {

    let line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString)

    guard let glyphRuns = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line) as? [CTRun] else { return []}

    var characterPaths = [CGPath]()

    for glyphRun in glyphRuns {
        guard let attributes = CTRunGetAttributes(glyphRun) as? [String:AnyObject] else { continue }
        let font = attributes[kCTFontAttributeName as String] as! CTFont

        for index in 0..<CTRunGetGlyphCount(glyphRun) {
            let glyphRange = CFRangeMake(index, 1)

            var glyph = CGGlyph()
            CTRunGetGlyphs(glyphRun, glyphRange, &glyph)

            var characterPosition = CGPoint()
            CTRunGetPositions(glyphRun, glyphRange, &characterPosition)
            characterPosition.x += position.x
            characterPosition.y += position.y

            if let glyphPath = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, glyph, nil) {
                var transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: characterPosition.x, ty: characterPosition.y)
                if let charPath = glyphPath.copy(using: &transform) {
                    characterPaths.append(charPath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return characterPaths
}
```

Comment: What is `self.characterPaths()` ?

Comment: @koen sorry check updated answer

Comment: This will support enough of NSAttributedString to be useful in many cases, but do remember that there are quite a few NSAttributedString attributes it doesn't handle, particularly text decorations (for example underline, strikethrough, and shadow).

Comment: prodigious answer. Much gratitude.